# Is it true that for p prime if $g^{(p-1)/2} = -1$ then g is a generator?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have figured out the reverse of this, that if $g$ is a generator then $g^{(p-1)/2} = -1$. I know that, using Fermat's Little Theorem, $g^{(p-1)} = 1$ for any element in $U_p$ and if $g^{(p-1)/2} = 1$ then it cannot be a generator. However, I'm unsure how to prove, or if it is even true, that if $g^{(p-1)/2} = -1$ then $g$ can only be a generator.

Comment: If $(p-1)/2$ is odd, then $(-1)^{(p-1)/2} = -1$, but $-1$ is rarely a generator!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You claim that $g^{(p-1)/2} = -1$ implies that $g$ is a generator.

Does it not follow that if $g$ is a generator, $g^3$ is also a generator?

Is this true for $p = 7$, where the group of units is cyclic of order 6?

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind how you reached that $g^3$ is a generator?

Comment: If $g^{(p-1)/2} = - 1$ then $(g^3)^{(p-1)/2} = (g^{(p-1)/2})^3 = (-1)^3 = -1$.

Answer (score 4):

$g^{(p-1)/2}=-1$ only implies that $g$ is a non-quadratic residue.
For instance $29$ is a non-quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{31}$, but it is not a generator, since $29=27^3$.
  $g$ is a generator iff $g^{(p-1)/q}\neq 1$ for every prime $q$ dividing $p-1$.
Of course, if $p$ is a prime of the form $2^k+1$ (like $17$ or $257$), being a non-quadratic residue and being a generator are the same thing, but that happens only in this particular case.